# How to convert Postgresql function having "row_to_json" to My Sql?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I want to change my database. But My Sql 5.6 not support row_to_json.

Comment: Have you tried lib_mysqludf_json: https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_json#readme ?

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I will try to use it, if possible. But .. If their is any other way. Please Share.